# rails delete unknown column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple Model called Token that has a user_id (integer) attribute.

If I do this:

```
Token.where(:user_id => 1)
```

it returns a record. But when I do:

```
Token.delete(:user_id => 1)
```

it gives me this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'id.user_id' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM `tokens` WHERE `id`.`user_id` = 1
```

For some reason it appends id to user_id in SQL statement. Why is it doing that? it works just fine for where clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`delete`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete) expects an id or an array of ids:

```
Token.delete(1)
Token.delete([2,3,4])
```

To delete records matching a condition, use [`delete_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all) instead:

```
Token.delete_all(:user_id => 1)
```

You can also append it to your query:

```
Token.where(:user_id => 1).delete_all
```

Both delete all tokens with `user_id` 1.

Answer (score 2):

What about reading some docs?

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete/class

```
delete(id) public
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Token.delete_all("tokens.user_id = ?", 1)
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation why this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

`Token.delete` expects a record ID, not condition hash ([documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/delete/class)).

You want something like this:

```
Token.where(:user_id => 1).delete_all
```

Comment: Ohh!! you finally started to help people in ROR... great :) :)